# solving $\frac{x}{3}+{[\frac{x}{3}]} = \sin(x) + [\sin(x)]$ for real x , in an efficient manner

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{x}{3}+{\left[\frac{x}{3}\right]}=\sin(x)+[\sin(x)]$$
I know the answer and the solution.
$$-1 \le \sin(x) \le 1\Rightarrow-2\le\sin(x)+[\sin(x)]\le 2 \Rightarrow -2 \le \frac{x}{3}+\left[\frac{x}{3}\right] \le 2  $$ now there are different situations :

$x=3$ is unacceptable
$$0 \le x \lt 3 \Rightarrow0 \le \frac{x}{3} \lt 1\Rightarrow \left[\frac{x}{3}\right]=0 \land[\sin(x)]=0\Rightarrow\frac{x}{3}=\sin(x)$$
which has 2 acceptable answers .
$$-3 \le x \lt 0 \Rightarrow-1 \le \frac{x}{3}\lt 0\Rightarrow \left[\frac{x}{3}\right] =-1\land [\sin(x)] = -1\Rightarrow\frac{x}{3} =\sin (x) $$ 
which has one acceptable answer. so the equation has 3 real answers .
I want to know if there is a better way to solve it. ( beautiful equation , isn't it?!)

Comment: So, $[\sin x]$ has three values $-1,0,1$ in three regions of $x$


Deal case by case

Comment: @Lucian: $[-\frac12] = -1$ and $[1]=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a more holistic way to solve this. The function $y\mapsto y+[y]$ is strictly increasing; in particular, it is one-to-one. Therefore $y+[y]=z+[z]$ if and only if $y=z$. So you can deduce right away that you're looking exactly for solutions to $\frac x3=\sin x$ (which is what you eventually found).